# Oracle db - remove ,, from email address

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm running below code and getting below results but I want to remove ,, and after ,, texts from email address and that email address should show in UPPER(PT_PARTNER_EMAIL) VALID_EMAIL_ID column.
How can I achieve this?

```
select party_id, pt_partner_id, pt_partner_email, upper(pt_partner_email) valid_email_id
from odi_ods_partner_dim
where length(pt_partner_email) > 3



PARTY_ID      PT_PARTNER_ID     PT_PARTNER_EMAIL                 VALID_EMAIL_ID
3223218102E17   10101363    DEEPAKSKORI@GMAIL.COM,,ALL     DEEPAKSKORI@GMAIL.COM,,ALL
5951118102E17   12059043    jalaj79@gmail.com,,            JALAJ79@GMAIL.COM,,
1113418102E17   12059044    hassanselim1993@gmail.com,,    HASSANSELIM1993@GMAIL.COM,,
2579321752017   36419244    drshetty@surgicare.co.in,,     DRSHETTY@SURGICARE.CO.IN,,
```

Comment: Also show us the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

please suggest how can I achive this.

try using these

0. Upper - Make all to upper case
   https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/upper.php
1. Instr  - find the position of ,,
   https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php
2. Substr - Cut from start to where ,, is
   https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php

e.g.

```
select upper( substr('wo++' , 1   ,  instr('wo++' , '++' )-1 ) )  from dual
--result WO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
with test1 as(
                select 'DEEPAKSKORI@GMAIL.COM,,ALL' VALID_EMAIL_ID from dual union all 
                select 'jalaj79@gmail.com,,' VALID_EMAIL_ID from dual union all 
                select    'hassanselim1993@gmail.com,,' VALID_EMAIL_ID from dual union all 
                select   'drshetty@surgicare.co.in,,' VALID_EMAIL_ID from dual
              )
select upper(substr(VALID_EMAIL_ID,1,instr(VALID_EMAIL_ID,',,')-1)) from test1
```

Result:

```
DEEPAKSKORI@GMAIL.COM
JALAJ79@GMAIL.COM
HASSANSELIM1993@GMAIL.COM
DRSHETTY@SURGICARE.CO.IN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `,,` substring exists using the `INSTR` function and then, if it does, remove it using `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`:

```sql
SELECT party_id,
       pt_partner_id,
       pt_partner_email,
       UPPER(
         CASE INSTR(pt_partner_email, ',,')
         WHEN 0
         THEN pt_partner_email
         ELSE SUBSTR(pt_partner_email, 1, INSTR(pt_partner_email, ',,') - 1)
         END
       ) AS valid_email_id
FROM   odi_ods_partner_dim
WHERE  LENGTH(pt_partner_email) > 3
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE odi_ods_partner_dim (PARTY_ID, PT_PARTNER_ID, PT_PARTNER_EMAIL) AS
SELECT '3223218102E17', 10101363, 'DEEPAKSKORI@EXAMPLE.COM,,ALL'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5951118102E17', 12059043, 'jalaj79@example.com,,'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1113418102E17', 12059044, 'hassanselim1993@example.com,,' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2579321752017', 36419244, 'drshetty@example.co.in,,'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC1234567890', 12345678, 'example@example.com'           FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: this includes an extra rows which does not contain `,,`.*

Outputs:

> | PARTY_ID | PT_PARTNER_ID | PT_PARTNER_EMAIL | VALID_EMAIL_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3223218102E17 | 10101363 | DEEPAKSKORI@EXAMPLE.COM,,ALL | DEEPAKSKORI@EXAMPLE.COM |
> | 5951118102E17 | 12059043 | jalaj79@example.com,, | JALAJ79@EXAMPLE.COM |
> | 1113418102E17 | 12059044 | hassanselim1993@example.com,, | HASSANSELIM1993@EXAMPLE.COM |
> | 2579321752017 | 36419244 | drshetty@example.co.in,, | DRSHETTY@EXAMPLE.CO.IN |
> | ABC1234567890 | 12345678 | example@example.com | EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=376e528fc4575dee598a3256c6da4208)*